# Why does the substitution of newlines using g/re/p only apply to every other line in Vim?

Tags: vim

Consider:

```
foo
bar
....
bar
baz
```

Then:

```
:g/bar/s/\n/\r\r/g
```

unexpectedly returns:

```
foo
bar

bar
bar

bar
bar

...
baz
```

when I want newlines after every `bar`.  Yet:

```
:g/bar/p
```

returns:

```
bar
bar
...
bar
```

as expected and if there are newlines between all the `bar`s I get what I expect--an extra newline after every line containing `bar`. I solved the problem by via:

```
:%s/\(bar.*\)\n/\1\r\r/g
```

but I'd really like to have a better understanding on what's going on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To understand what's going on at this level of detail, I think you have to reach for the source code. So, citing `vim-7.1.314/src/ex_cmds.c` (comment at the head of the definition of `ex_global()`):

> This is implemented in two passes: first we scan the file for the pattern and
>   set a mark for each line that (not) matches. secondly we execute the command
>   for each line that has a mark. This is required because after deleting
>   lines we do not know where to search for the next match.

Thus, if you delete a line in the `:g`'ed command, the mark for this line goes away too. If you create a line in the `:g`'ed command, it won't be marked, so the command won't execute on it. In your example, line 3 is joined with line 2, so the mark on line 3 disappears, and the next mark after line 2 is the one originally put on line 4.

Also, `ex_global` sets the `global_busy` variable, which causes a few commands, including `:s`, to behave slightly differently. I don't think the difference is relevant here though.

Answer (score 3):

[Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1788/why-does-the-substitution-of-newlines-using-g-re-p-only-apply-to-every-other-line/1797#1797) has answered your “why?”, but I thought you might be interested in a simpler way to do what you wanted.

> I want newlines after every `bar`.

Instead of replacing the line terminating character (thus joining the lines and losing the internal mark, per Gilles’ answer), add a blank line right before the end of each matching line. Use `$` to get a zero-width match right before the end of the line and insert a line break there (also no need for the `/g` modifier since the pattern will only match once per line).

```
:g/bar/s/$/\r/
```

Comment: That's fantastic!